# Add new value to current value to get total

Tags: c#, sql

I have this code to update the database,

```
string query1 =
  "UPDATE Points SET PNTS = "
+ "SWITCH ("
    + "  EmpName = '" + comboBox1.Text + "', '" + label15.Text + "'"
    + ", EmpName = '" + comboBox2.Text + "', '" + label16.Text + "'"
    + ", EmpName = '" + comboBox3.Text + "', '" + label17.Text + "'"
    + ", true, ''"
+ ")"
+ " WHERE EmpName in ('" + comboBox1.Text + "', '" + comboBox2.Text + "', '" + comboBox3.Text + "')"
```

;

In this query replace the current PNTS column value with new value,and I want to add this label.text values to current database PNTS values and get the total to PNTS column.

Please help me!!!

Comment: I strongly suggest you to using  [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: generally if you want to update a field by adding a value to the current value you do it like this: "UPDATE Points SET pnts = pnts + addvalue"

Comment: Do you want to add all labels values or just one of them ?

Comment: is it possible to move the switch out? my eye hurts :p

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, use parameterized queries to prevent sql injection, but to keep it easier for me (I don't know what the C# library for parameterized queries is) I'm just going to work with your current code and give you the fastest way to do it:

```
string query1 =
  "UPDATE Points SET PNTS = PNTS + "
+ "SWITCH ("
    + "  EmpName = '" + comboBox1.Text + "', '" + label15.Text + "'"
    + ", EmpName = '" + comboBox2.Text + "', '" + label16.Text + "'"
    + ", EmpName = '" + comboBox3.Text + "', '" + label17.Text + "'"
    + ", true, ''"
+ ")"
+ " WHERE EmpName in ('" + comboBox1.Text + "', '" + comboBox2.Text + "', '" + comboBox3.Text + "')"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help,but this is not the way I mean,your solution gives the answer as current value and new value together,ex:-current value=7,new value=3 answer=73,but I want the answer as 10!

Comment: The only reason that can happen is because your values are being saved in the database as non integers (eg varchar or similar) that's a database design flaw if you are using those fields to store numbers